# Cannot recognize input near 'DELETE' 'FROM' 'CTE' in statement

Tags: sql, hive

I want to drop duplicates in `mytable` if there are identical value in `col1`.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS RN
    FROM
        mytable
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN <> 1
```

I got error:

> Cannot recognize input near 'DELETE' 'FROM' 'CTE' in statement

Comment: Please show the layout of your table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Hive supports that syntax for `DELETE`.  Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable t
    WHERE t.id > (SELECT MIN(t2.id)  -- some sort of unique id
                  FROM t t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t.id
                 );
```

If you have complete duplicates, then the above won't work.  In the most recent versions of Hive you can use `MERGE`.  In older versions:

```
create table temp_t as
     select distinct t.*
     from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t
    select * from temp_t;
```

Of course, backup the table before trying this!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way: assuming you have UNIQUE ID Column.

```
  Delete from MyTable where ID in 
    (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS RN
        FROM mytable) a where RN <> 1)
```